# jQuery tooltip Widget to show tooltip on Click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How the new jQueryUI's tooltip widget can be modified to open the tooltip on click event on certain element's on document, while the others are still showing their tootip on mouseover event. So I tried to display the tool-tip values from **Ajax** calls. But it throws the error

**i) TypeError: d.addEventListener is not a function**

**ii) Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'**

Can anyone tell me the problem ?

**My HTML code:**

```
<button id="tt" name="dynamic-tool">Site Info</button>
```

**My jQuery code:**

```
jQuery('#tt').on({
  "click": function() {
    var ajaxURL = "http://192.168.2.135/shopping/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
    jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url :  ajaxURL,
                    data : {  action : 'toolTip'},
                    success : function(response) {
                        jQuery(this).tooltip({ items: "#tt", content: response});
                        jQuery(this).tooltip("open");
                   }
    });
    },
    "mouseout": function() {      
       jQuery(this).tooltip("disable");   
    }
});
```

**My function code:**

```
function toolTip(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
        echo 'You have been clicked';
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: What lib for tooltip do you use?

Comment: @kcp I used jquery-1.12.4.js and jquery-ui.js